# Escape Apostrophe In JQuery .text()

Tags: jquery

How can I escape the apostrophe in this line of code?
Using `&#39;` will only print out `&#39;` and not `'`.
By The way I'm walking about the apostrophe in the `We'd`.

```
$('.ContText-3').text('To find out more about how Lister, Jeter & Lloyd, CPAs can help you grow your business, contact us. We'd be happy to sit down with you, learn about your business, and share how we can help.');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.ContText-3').text('To find out more about how Lister, Jeter & Lloyd, CPAs can help you grow your business, contact us. We\'d be happy to sit down with you, learn about your business, and share how we can help.');
```

Comment: Wow that was simple.

Comment: @SethJ.Freeman - If you want to use encoded characters, use `.html()`. Otherwise, it's going to read the encoded "characters" as text with `.text()`, since that's what they are.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ContText-3').text("To find out more about how Lister, Jeter & Lloyd, CPAs can help you grow your business, contact us. We'd be happy to sit down with you, learn about your business, and share how we can help.");
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question as it doesn't escape the `'`. That's a work around which i'm not doing. Sandra Willford answered the question with what I was looking for. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @SethJ.Freeman - That's not a workaround at all, it's a sane way of doing it.

Comment: I have more `.text()` that have `"` in them and if I add `"` to surround the text, it messes up.

Comment: @SethJ.Freeman - That simply means you have to escape one or the other. It's up to you which "way" you prefer (note, PHP double-quotes are expanded, but in JS it makes no difference). It's not a workaround, though.